# Narrowing a type to its properties that are index signatures

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am building a type definition set that operates on a user provided type which represents the model of their "state".

One of the things I need to be able to do is to narrow the types of their model as I produce new types that are used and exposed to them.

I am having problems narrowing properties on an object that are index signatures.

For example:

```js
/**
 * Picks only the keys of a certain type
 * Taken from typelevel-ts
 */
type KeysOfType<A extends object, B> = {
  [K in keyof A]-?: A[K] extends B ? K : never;
}[keyof A];

interface Address {
  street: string;
  postCode: string;
}

interface Person {
  // I'd like to narrow to this property
  favouriteNumbers: {
    [id: string]: number;
  };
  name: string;
  address: Address;
}

type PersonIndexSignatures = Pick<
  Person, 
  KeysOfType<Person, { [key: string]:  any; }>
>;

type PersonIndexSignaturesKeys = keyof PersonIndexSignatures;
// "favouriteNumbers" | "address"
```

As you can see above my attempt to narrow `Person` based on `{ [key: string]:  any; }` yields both the `favouriteNumbers` and `address` keys.

Is there any trick I can use to narrow the type to `favouriteNumbers` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

First, how do we tell the difference between `Person["favouriteNumbers"]` and `Person["address"]`?

This looks promising:

```js
type A = keyof Person["favouriteNumbers"];
// string | number

type B = keyof Person["address"];
// "street" | "postcode"
```

`string` extends `A` but not `B`:

```js
type A = string extends keyof Person["favouriteNumbers"] ? true : false;
// true

type B = string extends keyof Person["address"] ? true : false;
// false
```

We can hack that check into your `KeysOfType` (you can probably clean this up):

```js
type KeysOfType<A extends object, B extends { [key: string]: any }> = {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends B ? string extends keyof A[K] ? K : never : never;
}[keyof A];
```

And then:

```js
type PersonIndexSignaturesKeys = keyof PersonIndexSignatures;
// "favouriteNumbers"
```